# How can I print this 2D array in Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I created a 2D array and want to print it in this format:

Input:

```
history = [['T:18:00,', 'Main,', 'exit'], ['T:10:00,', 'Main,', 'enter']]
```

Output:

```
Main (T:18:00 - T:10:00)
```

Comment: What if there are other values than `Main`? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: yes, I tried. But I have no clue to do that...Do you have idea on it?